# Dialogflow - Dealing with user discrepancy when coding fulfilment

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

When coding fulfilment for Dialogflow (API.AI) is there a way to deal with discrepancies in user responses without having to do a full if statement for all the possible ways a user could say the same thing? A.K.A the manual way.

For example, if I'm asking where the user located and they say they're from the  West Midlands, which is one of my locations - do I have to do an IF statement that looks something like this:

```
if (location === 'West Midlands' || 'west Midlands' || 'w midlands' || 'w mid') {}
```

Or can I pass it back to Dialogflow where it can handle the users input using the AI or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an [Entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities/developer-entities) that represents the locations you support.

Each of the possibly values in your Entity can have a canonical value and then the aliases that the user can enter that will map to this canonical value. When the parameter is sent to your fulfillment, the canonical value will be sent. (If you needed exactly what they entered, it is available as well, but you should use the canonical value for your tests.)

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I don't know why I hadn't thought of this originally. Thanks for jogging my memory, haha!

Comment: i wrote the answer, was about to press submit when i saw you already posted this :)

Comment: @sid8491 - Go ahead and post it! You may phrase it in a way that someone else in the future will better understand when they run into the same problem.

Comment: @SlappedProgrammer - Hey, we all need a reminder sometimes. Glad it helps!